# Samsung laptop Ubuntu sees the wifi but does not connect

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, laptop, lts

I know there are a thousand of these questions around, but I tried a few and did not get any results, so I decided to open a new question. The NetworkConnections thing sees the wifi connection, but does not connect and there is no way that I see to tell it to connect manually.

I'd like to resolve the issue without resorting to wired connection, since I use this laptop in university and want to use the wifi there as well.

Here are some data that was suggested by a helpful tooltip:

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2232:1041  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo lshw -class network` output:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0600000-f067ffff memory:f0680000-f068ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 18:67:b0:4f:b0:68
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:25 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0500000-f0500fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
```

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux nikolay-300E5EV-300E4EV-270E5EV-270E4EV-2470EV 3.19.0-33-generic #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Were you able to connect to WiFi before? Is it specific to one SSID or to any SSIDs?

Comment: @AzkerM 1. It was connected during installation and the first time I booted it. After that it became like this.
2. What's SSID?

Comment: Also, it was connected without problems when I was using the "boot up without installing option".

Comment: [**SSID**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Service_set_identification_.28SSID.29) refers to WiFi name which you choose to connect. Is this only for your specific WiFi or have you tried connecting to another WiFi network.. Well, a mobile hotspot maybe, just for the testing purpose?

Comment: @AzkerM Don't have any in my vicinity.

Comment: What kernel are you using? `uname -a` Thanks

Comment: @AzkerM Added to question post.

Comment: Have you tried installing anything?  Backports?  Your kernel should have supported that wifi card as it has been supported since at least Ubuntu 13.10 with the 3.11 kernel.  What does `sudo modprobe ath9k` do?

Comment: @AzkerM `sudo modprobe ath9k` does nothing. Tried running `sudo apt-get install g++`, got a `dpkg` error, ran the suggested configuration process. Tried running the g++ install again and lo and behold, all of a sudden there was internet!

Comment: @clearkimura If you look really carefully, you will see that about an hour before your comment I already did that. And due to how things work, I can accept it only in two days.

Comment: @Sunspawn My bad, I didn't notice there was an answer while viewing your question in "Review" mode. I guess this is another thing that may be easily missed when doing reviews.

Answer (score 1):

Not an all-encompassing answer, but in my case I was able to somehow resolve the issue while checking stuff for AzkerM's questions in the comments:

1. I tried running `sudo apt-get install g++` to check if I could install something.
2. The result was `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`
3. I did it and tried running the g++ install again.
4. ??? (magic happened as far as I am concerned, no idea what did it)
5. Profit! (there was internet all of a sudden.)

Pretty sure that running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` did the trick here.